# Sum of columns in mariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

[image]

What could be the best way to display only those rows where sum of scm,vd n quality is (e.g) greater than 20. all of them are int(4). And i am using PHP +mariaDB.

Comment: P.S: ignore the numbers i forgot to blur it out

Comment: `SELECT * from foo where (scm+vd+quality ) >20`

Comment: If you just posted sensitive information, please upload a blurred image. Please also share the code you have written so far, you will be more likely to get some help.

Comment: tbh when i did the same thing it it showed me 0 in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE (scm + vd + quality) > 20    -- The sum of the columns >20
  AND LEAST(scm, vd, quality) > 0  -- and none is zero
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple query to get result:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE (scm+vd+quality ) >20;
```

Comment: @bdesai can we also put a check on separate column that it should not be empty?

Comment: give an example

Comment: I want to import rows where sum in greater than 20 and none of them(vd,scm,quality) is 0

Comment: so got solution?